# Asynchronous Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sapui5

currently, we are using the SAP HANA Database. To get data, we will use a Node.JS-API, which we will call via AJAX, to get the advantages by async. So here is the problem:

We have many pages where we need the same data (e.g. customer data). To do so, I wanted to create a Library, which does the actual data calls, so that i just need to call `db.getCustomer([ID])`. In order to get a return value from AJAX, I have to set `async: false` within the AJAX call.

My question is now, is it possible to create a data-call-library asynchronously? Is it a good practice to encapsulate the databinding (using so called DAO)? 
I'm a bit confused, because another dev told me to just use the same AJAX-call over and over again, to not loose the async and it is a better practice anyway.

Here is my actual AJAX-call as an example:

```
getCustomer: function( CID ) {
            var aUrl = 'http://example.com/api/customer/' + CID,
                returnData
            ;
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: aUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    returnData = data;
                }
            });
            return returnData;
        },

// other ajax calls 
// to get the data via 1-liner
```

thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it makes no sense to return data from a callback in a synchronous function; normally, you would store the returned callback data into your model, so your view/controller gets automatically updated.

If you really need your method to return async data, have a look at [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or Promises

Comment: so the solution here might be setting up the model itself within my functions library (or, as you mentioned, using promises) ?

Comment: If your aim is to create a functions library, I would choose to have your methods return a promise (resolve or reject)

Comment: thank you! after some research it works just super fine now :) return $.ajax({...}); and then --> getCustomer(CID).then() or .success() solves now all my problems!

Comment: Impressed you got it working so quickly -- most people have a hard time grasping the concepts (and power) of promises! :-) In addition, promises can also work magic when working with events, DOM rendering, etc. For a nice article on Promises, see https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970 Happy coding!